# Groovy script not able to get job within a folder

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I had this piece of groovy code on my Jenkins job, and it worked as a charm:

```
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob("$job_name")
println("Job: $job")
```

Now i changed the job in question to a folder in the root of Jenkins, and the code simply doesn't work anymore. The returned object comes as null. I tried referencing the folder name on before the `$job_name` var, but it still don't work.

Does anyone knows a way to get the instance of a job that's within a folder?

Comment: have you read the docs (the function you are calling is deprecated and it says it shouldn't be called) http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Hudson.html#getJob-java.lang.String-

Comment: I know. But i couldn't find which function replaced it.
The method still work, nonetheless. For jobs on the root of the Jenkins.

Comment: Yes it would be nice to know what else to use and/or how the `String name` should be written exactly to refer to a specific job ...

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is

```
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("folder/job-name")
```

with `folder/job-name` if the UI link to it is `https://your.jenkins/job/folder/job/job-name/`